# Jquery Hover over Text

Tags: jquery, html, css, browser, web

I finished my show dynamic image over text project.
The only thing left for me is that everytime the mouse gets in the first frame will resize my browser window until I move my mouse and the hover image gets adjusted.

My code:

```
<script>
$(function(){
$("a[data-src*=.jpg]").thumbPopup({
    imgSmallFlag: "",
    imgLargeFlag: ""
});
});
</script>
<div align="right" >
<a id="imagehover" data-src="http://i.imgur.com/8oDIE7T.jpg">
Im a cat, and im not working as intended on my first frame :(</a>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qvjfjwre/

Do you have any idea how to stop that stupid resizing on first frame?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You should include your code in your question - this safeguards against link rot.

Comment: Thanks, included my code :)